How to run computations on other rows efficiently
I am working with a Polars DataFrame and need to perform computations on each row using values from other rows. Currently, I am using the map_elements method, but it is not efficient.
In the following example, I add two new columns to a DataFrame:

sum_lower: The sum of all elements that are smaller than the current element.
max_other: The maximum value from the DataFrame, excluding the current element.

Here is my current implementation:
import polars as pl

COL_VALUE = "value"

def fun_sum_lower(current_row, df):
    tmp_df = df.filter(pl.col(COL_VALUE) < current_row[COL_VALUE])
    sum_lower = tmp_df.select(pl.sum(COL_VALUE)).item()
    return sum_lower

def fun_max_other(current_row, df):
    tmp_df = df.filter(pl.col(COL_VALUE) != current_row[COL_VALUE])
    max_other = tmp_df.select(pl.col(COL_VALUE)).max().item()
    return max_other

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pl.DataFrame({COL_VALUE: [3, 7, 1, 9, 4]})

    df = df.with_columns(
        pl.struct([COL_VALUE])
        .map_elements(lambda row: fun_sum_lower(row, df), return_dtype=pl.Int64)
        .alias("sum_lower")
    )

    df = df.with_columns(
        pl.struct([COL_VALUE])
        .map_elements(lambda row: fun_max_other(row, df), return_dtype=pl.Int64)
        .alias("max_other")
    )

    print(df)

The output of the above code is:
shape: (5, 3)
┌───────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ value ┆ sum_lower ┆ max_other │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 3     ┆ 1         ┆ 9         │
│ 7     ┆ 8         ┆ 9         │
│ 1     ┆ 0         ┆ 9         │
│ 9     ┆ 15        ┆ 7         │
│ 4     ┆ 4         ┆ 9         │
└───────┴───────────┴───────────┘

While this code works, it is not efficient due to the use of lambdas and row-wise operations.
Is there a more efficient way to achieve this in Polars, without using lambdas, iterating over rows, or running Python code?
I also tried using Polars methods: cum_sum, group_by_dynamic, and rolling, but I don't think those can be used for this task.

For your specific use case you don't really need join, you can calculate values with window functions.

pl.Expr.shift() to exclude current row.
pl.Expr.cum_sum() to calculate sum of all elements up to the current row.
pl.Expr.max() to calculate max.
pl.Expr.bottom_k() to calculate 2 largest elements so then we can take pl.Expr.min() as second largest.

(
    df
    .sort("value")
    .with_columns(
        sum_lower = pl.col.value.shift(1).cum_sum().fill_null(0),
        max_other =
        pl.when(pl.col.value.max() != pl.col.value)
        .then(pl.col.value.max())
        .otherwise(pl.col.value.bottom_k(2).min()) 
    )
)

shape: (5, 3)
┌───────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ value ┆ sum_lower ┆ max_other │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 0         ┆ 9         │
│ 3     ┆ 1         ┆ 9         │
│ 4     ┆ 4         ┆ 9         │
│ 7     ┆ 8         ┆ 9         │
│ 9     ┆ 15        ┆ 7         │
└───────┴───────────┴───────────┘

You can also use pl.DataFrame.with_row_index() to keep current order so you can revert to it at the end with pl.DataFrame.sort().
(
    df.with_row_index()
    .sort("value")
    .with_columns(
        sum_lower = pl.col.value.shift(1).cum_sum().fill_null(0),
        max_other =
        pl.when(pl.col.value.max() != pl.col.value)
        .then(pl.col.value.max())
        .otherwise(pl.col.value.bottom_k(2).min()) 
    )
    .sort("index")
    .drop("index")
)

Another possible solution would be to use DuckDB integration with Polars.
Using window functions, getting advantage of excellent DuckDB windows framing options.

max(arg, n) to calculate top 2 largest elements.

import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        d.value,
        coalesce(sum(d.value) over(
            order by d.value
            rows unbounded preceding
            exclude current row
        ), 0) as sum_lower,
        max(d.value) over(
            rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
            exclude current row
        ) as max_other
    from df as d
""").pl()

shape: (5, 3)
┌───────┬───────────────┬───────────┐
│ value ┆ sum_lower     ┆ max_other │
│ ---   ┆ ---           ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ decimal[38,0] ┆ i64       │
╞═══════╪═══════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 0             ┆ 9         │
│ 3     ┆ 1             ┆ 9         │
│ 4     ┆ 4             ┆ 9         │
│ 7     ┆ 8             ┆ 9         │
│ 9     ┆ 15            ┆ 7         │
└───────┴───────────────┴───────────┘

Or using lateral join:
import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
    select
        d.value,
        coalesce(s.value, 0) as sum_lower,
        m.value as max_other
    from df as d,
        lateral (select sum(t.value) as value from df as t where t.value < d.value) as s,
        lateral (select max(t.value) as value from df as t where t.value != d.value) as m
""").pl()

shape: (5, 3)
┌───────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ value ┆ sum_lower ┆ max_other │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 3     ┆ 1         ┆ 9         │
│ 7     ┆ 8         ┆ 9         │
│ 1     ┆ 0         ┆ 9         │
│ 9     ┆ 15        ┆ 7         │
│ 4     ┆ 4         ┆ 9         │
└───────┴───────────┴───────────┘

duplicate values
pure polars solution above works well if there're no duplicate values, but if there are, you can also work around it.
Here're 2 examples depending on whether you want to keep original order or not:
# not keeping original order
(
    df
    .select(pl.col.value.value_counts()).unnest("value")
    .sort("value")
    .with_columns(
        sum_lower = pl.col.value.shift(1).cum_sum().fill_null(0),
        max_other =
        pl.when(pl.col.value.max() != pl.col.value)
        .then(pl.col.value.max())
        .otherwise(pl.col.value.bottom_k(2).min()),
        value = pl.col.value.repeat_by("count")
    ).drop("count").explode("value")
)

# keeping original order
(
    df.with_row_index()
    .group_by("value").agg("index")
    .sort("value")
    .with_columns(
        sum_lower = pl.col.value.shift(1).cum_sum().fill_null(0),
        max_other =
        pl.when(pl.col.value.max() != pl.col.value)
        .then(pl.col.value.max())
        .otherwise(pl.col.value.bottom_k(2).min()) 
    )
    .explode("index")
    .sort("index")
    .drop("index")
)


Minor: Note that the non-join solutions are not equivalent to OP's map_elements solution if there are duplicates in values.

yes I had it mentioned previously but removed from the answer. Window functions solutions can be adjusted easily for multiple values though - I'm operating here with 'current row' just for the sake of examples, but it can be changed to 'current value'

@roman, your polars solutions are super fast! Thank you for those. Could you write an example with window function and multiple values?

@Batawi added some examples

You could try non-equi joins: .join_where()
df_sum = (
   df.unique("value") # summing requires unique LHS
     .join_where(df, pl.col.value > pl.col.value_right)
     .group_by("value")
     .sum()
)

df_max = (
   df.join_where(df, pl.col.value != pl.col.value_right)
     .group_by("value")
     .max()
)

(df.select("value")
   .join(df_sum, on="value", how="left")
   .join(df_max, on="value", how="left")
)

shape: (5, 3)
┌───────┬─────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ value ┆ value_right ┆ value_right_right │
│ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---               │
│ i64   ┆ i64         ┆ i64               │
╞═══════╪═════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 3     ┆ 1           ┆ 9                 │
│ 7     ┆ 8           ┆ 9                 │
│ 1     ┆ null        ┆ 9                 │
│ 9     ┆ 15          ┆ 7                 │
│ 4     ┆ 4           ┆ 9                 │
└───────┴─────────────┴───────────────────┘

Although, for these specific tasks - it doesn't really scale to larger data.

Alternatively, if you can sort your data, the problem essentially becomes .cum_sum() + .max() operations (with a couple of "shifts") - which are extremely fast operations.
(df
  .sort("value")
  .with_columns(
     pl.when(pl.col.value.is_last_distinct())
       .then(pl.col.value.cum_sum())
       .shift()
       .forward_fill()
       .fill_null(0)
       .alias("sum_lower")
  )
  .with_columns(max_other = pl.col.value.max())
  .with_columns(
     pl.when(pl.col.value == pl.col.max_other)
       .then(pl.col.value.rle().get(-2).struct.field("value"))
       .otherwise(pl.col.max_other)
       .alias("max_other")
  )
)

shape: (5, 3)
┌───────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ value ┆ sum_lower ┆ max_other │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64   ┆ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 0         ┆ 9         │
│ 3     ┆ 1         ┆ 9         │
│ 4     ┆ 4         ┆ 9         │
│ 7     ┆ 8         ┆ 9         │
│ 9     ┆ 15        ┆ 7         │
└───────┴───────────┴───────────┘

What is happening?
If we add some duplicate values to your example.
df = pl.DataFrame({"value": [3, 7, 1, 9, 4, 4, 3, 3]})

(df.sort("value")
   .with_columns(is_last = pl.col.value.is_last_distinct())
   .with_columns(pl.when(pl.col.value.is_last_distinct()).then(pl.col.value.cum_sum()).alias("sum0"))
   .with_columns(pl.col("sum0").shift().alias("sum1"))
   .with_columns(pl.col("sum1").forward_fill().alias("sum2"))
)

shape: (8, 5)
┌───────┬─────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ value ┆ is_last ┆ sum0 ┆ sum1 ┆ sum2 │
│ ---   ┆ ---     ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64   ┆ bool    ┆ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═══════╪═════════╪══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 1     ┆ true    ┆ 1    ┆ null ┆ null │
│ 3     ┆ false   ┆ null ┆ 1    ┆ 1    │ # from value=1
│ 3     ┆ false   ┆ null ┆ null ┆ 1    │
│ 3     ┆ true    ┆ 10   ┆ null ┆ 1    │
│ 4     ┆ false   ┆ null ┆ 10   ┆ 10   │ # from value=3
│ 4     ┆ true    ┆ 18   ┆ null ┆ 10   │
│ 7     ┆ true    ┆ 25   ┆ 18   ┆ 18   │ # from value=4
│ 9     ┆ true    ┆ 34   ┆ 25   ┆ 25   │ # from value=7
└───────┴─────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘

With the data sorted, .is_last_distinct() gives you the last value in each run/streak and we shift it 1 step forward so that the first value in each run/streak now has the "sum_lower" (i.e. the cum_sum from the "previous run").
.forward_fill() is used so that each value in the run is assigned the sum_lower (in the possible case of duplicates).

The "max_other" logic seems to be that you then want the .max() value in all cases except for the last, i.e. when value == max.
With sorted data, .rle() is a fast way to give you a unique set of values and retain their sorted order.
df.sort("value").select(pl.col.value.rle())

shape: (5, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ value     │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {1,1}     │
│ {3,3}     │
│ {2,4}     │
│ {1,7}     │ # <-
│ {1,9}     │
└───────────┘


What version of polars do you have? I am getting error 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'join_where'. My polars version is 1.6.0

I'm using 1.11.0 - join_where was added in 1.7.0. I've added an alternative approach for earlier versions. Using join_where is not really efficient for large data anyways. (for the specific calculations you're doing)
